Where on Stackexchange could i post work on new factoring methods
What board can i post work showing original framework for factoring methods, so that i can get insight from others with more expertise on why such a framework functions?  I have some understanding now, but could use more.  Where will it be on topic?
Since factoring methods, which is all I'm willing to share right now, is directly related to many forms of online encryption, is it related enough for cryptography boards?  There is a direct relation to many public-private key generation methods, so would it qualify?

You did not show any, just wrote your paper and published it.

What mean?  I haven't posted any work yet on stack exchange, since that is what gets my questions closed for making people upset.  I want to know what board to post to that won't get taken down where people can study the framework and try to answer why using known factors of one number leads to factors of compared number.

In reality, normal factoring is just comparing a set of numbers against a product with unknown factors.  I'm discussing a method that needs to be done with only one compared number (as a starting point) and leads quickly to the unknown factors.

If I'm willing to share my starting discovery,  and allow others to possibly end up at answers i wish to sell, isn't that somewhere in the range of ethical behavior?  One method leads to the others, as long as prior education doesn't keep you from outside-the-box thinking.

"normal factoring is just comparing a set of numbers against a product with unknown factors" - that doesn't sound right.  The best algorithms strive to construct two values $a, b$ with $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod n$ (and if $a \not\equiv b, -b$, this immediately yields a factorization).  That doesn't sound like "comparing a set of numbers..."

Sure, how long does that method take?  How many values of a and b are possible to use to get to correct answer?  A lot.

If a method requires a lot of trial and error, it is not the best way, and will take an unknown amount of computaion for any given number.  If you can start at ONE easily found point, and run an operation that devolves to the correct answer (or its multiple, giving a common factor number), is that not much more efficient?

I am still hoping for an answer of where to post original work for scrutiny.  I will even give a detailed description of what i understand of it, so long as it won't be censored in some fashion.

your techniques sound very unusual, but your observations about the other comments show that you are pretty much a beginner; so follow the suggestions in the answers (e.g., eprint.iacr.org) and see what transpires. If you think you can avoid trial and error in factorization you will most likely be disappointed since the distribution of primes has features of randomness and you are looking at massive intervals when considering RSA type moduli

TL;DR all the best known factoring methods for large moduli are randomized algorithms.

StackExchange consists of a set of Q/A sites, trying to build a knowledge base. As such it is a knowledge base of known information, supported by a community of experts and enthusiasts.
Stack Exchange is not the best place to have research published. You won't become famous here, nor is it allowed to advertise your algorithms and schemes without reason (the reason being that it is directly related to a question that somebody asks).
As indicated, the best way forward is to publish your findings in a paper. If your scheme has merit then it can be a base for finding work within the field of study (math or cryptography in this case). That will ultimately provide you much more value than selling information on eBay or similar.

Okay.  Thanks much

If the question is help understanding a discovery, is that not a valid question for a forum of experts?  Known experts are already stumped, and of no use, except to show these discoveries (correct or not) are new and different.

Also, not looking to get famous.  Just to make an income on my hobby.  Some people mine bitcoins; i mine for answers to unsolved math questions.  I even tried my hand at squaring a circle since its impossible.  The result was a new variation of the standard model for finding the sqrt of pi.  I wasn't successful, but came as close as is possible, to date.  At least someone at a university looked at it and told me about the standard model, which i didn't know.  I learned something, even though i didn't have an eduction in the subject previously.  It was fun trying.

Thanks to mods for email explaining that i comment too much.  I am working on adding all information in body of questions,  rather than adding info through comments.

Well, help can be performed in different ways. If it means "help" in answering a question that wasn't already covered then yes, most people are willing to help. If it means evaluating a scheme or system or asking for more generic help then this is off topic on most of stack exchange. Now if you have any specific questions on e.g. an analysis technique then you're free to ask.

Ok.  Thank you.  I'm starting to get what's expected of me, albeit slowly.

That's great. Take your time to digest all of it and don't try to over-extend or over-ask and everything will be fine. Beware that answerers are not obliged to answer any follow up questions or go into discussion. Asking for clarification is more likely to result in a comment or update of an answer.

Your best bet is to publish it on the iacr eprint archive. Here's the link to submit papers. https://eprint.iacr.org/submit.
Why is this the best avenue? The eprint archive contains a large portion of the published literature on cryptography. It's arguably the main reference; most people in this field check it very often.
Any new publication on their targeted topic quickly gets the community's attention, especially if you have interesting insights on factoring (see Schnorr's paper for a recent occurrence).
Ethics. It's fair to say that one would not expect any catastrophic outcome from what will be shared. The way the question is formulated doesn't lead to thinking there's any disastrous outcome to be expected. Nonetheless, share your insights with the community and get feedback. There have been tons of public papers on factoring that weren't unethical or broke the internet.

I was speaking of the ethics of selling refined methods on ebay.  Previous work i posted was taken down or closed.  I mentioned in a previous post that a partial description with worksheets is available on ebay, since it can't be taken down.  My question was closed because the mods thought i was making a sales pitch of some sort.

As far as breaking the internet, i have been told everything from it is armageddon to it can be easily fixed.  This in relation to factoring AND discrete log discoveries.  I only know what I've been told, since i am not an expert in online cryptography schemes,  but i am learning.

Regarding censoring: again, that's an advantage of the archive. This forum has a policy which we must follow. The archive is designed so that anything related to cryptography can freely be published (also, not matter how wrong/correct it is). So there's nothing left to do than just write it up in a paper and publish. You're guaranteed to have tons of feedback very soon.


What board can i post work

What make you think there is such board?
Before asking "What board" you should have asked if you can post any work.
The answer would be: No, you can't. Stackexchange is not the place to post any works and to ask for feedback.
